Origin not transmited to sveltekit backend
I want to set the origin of any fetch request I do in my app. At some point, I want to send a request from the frontend of my sveltekit app to the backend of my sveltekit app. I use the function handleFetch to do so. It works perfectly with POST request but not with the GET requests, the origin field doesn't exist. Other headers like Referer seems to work in both case. Do you have any idea on why ?
